# pyplot prevent x-axis overlap labels

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm plotting some data through pyplot and the code is as follows
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(x['name'], x['accuracy'], label='Accuracy')
plt.plot(x['name'], x['precision'], label='Precision')
plt.plot(x['name'], x['recall'], label='Recall')
plt.plot(x['name'], x['f1'], label='F1')
plt.plot(x['name'], x['fpr'], label='FPR')
plt.show()
plt.close()
```

I have about 250 labels in the x-axis. they are overlapping when plotting using the above code. Therefore, I set the label orientation to vertical

```
plt.xticks(x['name'], rotation='vertical')
```

I also tried changing the label size. Then can't real label as they are so small

```
plt.tick_params(axis='x', which='major', labelsize=2)
```

I've about 250 labels and these are just text labels so I can't only display some x-values unlike when the x-axis is date or some continuous value. How can I show all x-labels without overlapping?

Comment: Probably you can't unless you set a very large figure size. Have thought about just showing the five best models or replacing the name by indices? Otherwise if you just want to display all results, a heatmap would be an option, too.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. But just wondering isn't there any way to increase the gap between labels so the chart will auto-resize?

Comment: No, it's the inverse. You need a larger figure, then labels will not overlap.